# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick?

Tags: java, android, onclick

Could anyone please help me to solve this error?. It's displaying well pdf file but coused when click to navigation buttons.

I have tried in different ways to solve it but apparently I can't get to the solution? do you think it concerns the Pdf or the code?

This is the log of the crash:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

Here my `MainActivity` class:

```
package com.android.strongguide;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public PDFView pdfView;
public float zoomValue=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("Guide.pdf")
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
//                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
//                .swipeHorizontal(false)
//                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
//                .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
//                .password(null)
//                .scrollHandle(null)
//                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(10)
//                .autoSpacing(true) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
//                .fitEachPage(true) // fit each page to the view, else smaller pages are scaled relative to largest page.
//                .pageSnap(true) // snap pages to screen boundaries
//                .pageFling(true) // make a fling change only a single page like ViewPager
//                .nightMode(false) // toggle night mode
                .load();
    }
    public void nextPage(View view) { pdfView.jumpTo(pdfView.getCurrentPage() +1,true);
    }
    public void prevPage(View view) { pdfView.jumpTo(pdfView.getCurrentPage()-1, true);
    }
    public void  zoomIn(View view){
        ++zoomValue;
        pdfView.zoomTo(zoomValue);
        pdfView.loadPages();
    }
    public void  zoomOut(View view){
        if (zoomValue!=1){
            --zoomValue;
            pdfView.zoomTo(zoomValue);
            pdfView.loadPages();
        }
}

}
```

Here my `.XML` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Prev"
            android:onClick="prevPage"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
            android:text="Next"
            android:onClick="nextPage" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="zoomIn" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button4"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="zoomOut" />
        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which onClick() method are you getting crash as there are four and also share pdf.jumpTo () method .

Comment: thanks dear. fixed issue by
PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("Guide.pdf")
to
pdfView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("Guide.pdf")